# Conditionally filter elements of a group based on max value of another column (dplyr::group_by)

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, conditional-statements, subset

```
df <- read.csv("http://www.sharecsv.com/dl/da89d0f973c81ad8c0ff4bcb0e7293b0/testdata.csv")
df %>% dplyr::group_by(TOF)
```

I want to look at duplicated `TOF` values. Whenever a duplicated value is found (in other words, `TOF` values belonging to the same dplyr::group), I want to keep those that satisfy the following condition:

```
intFT > max(intFT) * 0.1 ### this condition is valid within-group, i.e. max(intFT) refers to the highest intFT in a certain TOF group grouped by dplyr::group_by
```

Furthermore, in every `TOF` group, only **top three elements with the highest** `intFT` should be kept.

`NA` values should **not** be removed.

This returns an incorrect solution:

```
df %>% dplyr::group_by(TOF) %>% filter(intFT > max(intFT) * 0.1)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it look at mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>%filter(mpg > max(mpg) * .9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your data but something like this could work

```
df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(TOF) %>% 
  add_tally %>% 
  mutate(remove_it = if_else(n > 2 | intFT < max(intFT) * 0.1),"yes","no") %>% 
  filter(remove_it == "no") %>% 
  top_n(3)
```